# How can I make http request using int header in swift

Tags: swift, httprequest

I need to make an http request with one Int header, but all the ways that I try uses dictionaries with type [String : String].

How can I make a header [String : Int]???

ps. I'm using swift 4.2

I’m using this func to make the request, if I try to change the parameter headers to [String : Int] or put the dictionary directly in allHTTPHeaderFields I get this error: Cannot assign value of type '[String : Int]' to type '[String : String]?'

```
`static func fetch(url: URL, headers: [String: String]? = nil, completion: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) {

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    if headers != nil {
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [headers]
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil else { completion (nil, error); return }

        guard let data = data else { print("No data"); return }

        completion(data, nil)

    }.resume()
}`
```

I also tried to use some frameworks like Moya, but I’m having the same problems there

Comment: Does it not work if you just convert your Int to a String?

Comment: No, I tried this already, it works like if the request was with no headers at all. I also tested in postman, when I add the Int header it works perfectly.

Comment: That's odd.  Headers don't have any type metadata, they shouldn't care whether it was a String or Int originally.  Can you show the code where you tried to send it?

Comment: The code where you converted it to a string, I mean.  And make sure to edit it into the question - comments can get deleted, and it's hard to read code without any formatting anyway.

Comment: Sorry, it's the first time I'm asking a question, I edit the question and added the code to the scope

Comment: That all seems all right at a glance, but it doesn't show where you're building the header data.

Comment: Please check Apple documentation you must pass value type [String : String] , can not pass [String : Int] , if you want to make sure about this just use this function after setting headers open func value(forHTTPHeaderField field: String) -> String? in case of [String :  Int] it return nil always